# How to use Composables from common in Compose Web?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, compose-desktop, compose-web, jetpack-compose-web

I made a simple Compose Web project using [the getting started guide](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Web/Getting_Started/README.md). It works when just using the Web API, so Composables like `Div` and `Span`.

However, the whole point of multiplatform is being able to reuse components, so I added `common` and `jvm` (Compose Desktop, not Android) modules. I can use the Composables from `common` in `jvm` just fine, but when I use them in the Web project, I get errors in my browser console: `CompositionLocal X not present`, where X includes `LocalDensity`, `LocalLayoutDirection`, `LocalViewConfiguration`, `LocalFontFamilyResolver` and `LocalInputManager`. I might be able to provide those one by one, but this is just setup that should be automatic. So, what can I do to use my `common` Composables in `js` with Compose Web?

The `build.gradle.kts` file contains:

```
plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform")
  id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

kotlin {
  jvm("desktop") { ... }
  js(IR) {
    browser()
    binaries.executable()
  }
  sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting { 
      dependencies {
        api(compose.runtime)
        api(compose.foundation)
        api(compose.material)
      }
    }
    val desktopMain by getting { ... }
    val jsMain by getting { 
      dependencies {
        api(compose.web.core)
        api(compose.runtime)
      }
    }
  }
}
// plus the afterEvaluate workaround from the guide, which isn't relevant for this question
```

Currently using Kotlin 1.8.10 and Compose 1.3.1